# vba error unable to set the hidden property of the range class Error 1004

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access, excel-formula

when you have the control from the Form there is no Problem

 but if you have it from the worksheet itself then it works actually but with Error:1004 
so just use ( On Error Resume Next)

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
Dim wsMon As Worksheet
Set wsMon = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Montag")
On Error Resume Next
Select Case ComboBox1.ListIndex
       Case 0
            xHide (False)
            wsMon.Rows("12:25").EntireRow.Hidden = True
            xHide (True)
       Case 1
            xHide (False)
            wsMon.Rows("12:25").EntireRow.Hidden = False
            wsMon.Rows("19:25").EntireRow.Hidden = True
            xHide (True)
       Case 2
            xHide (False)
            wsMon.Rows("12:25").EntireRow.Hidden = False
            xHide (True)
End Select

End Sub
```

xHide is a Boolean Function :
true

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
```

or False

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
```

Comment: Which specific line gives the error?  Also, isn't `Worksheet.Rows.EntireRow` a completely unnecessary redundancy?  (Using `On Error Resume Next` should generally be the *last* thing you try, when completely unavoidable)

Comment: It worked for me as written with no errors.

Answer (score 1):

If I run this and my sheet is password protected, I get the same error.  Try adding this line (you can re-protect it if necessary):

```
wksMain.Unprotect (conPassword)
```

Also, you shouldn't need the on error resume next, and if you do use that you should add Go To 0 whenever you are past the code you need it for.